# I want to make the discord bot to not react to a certain user when they edit a message, but it doesn't work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make it so a discord bot won't react to a certain user when they make say an edit on a message, however it doesn't quite work. My current code is

```
from discord.ext import commands

id = id

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')




@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    
    if message.author.id == id:
        pass

    else:

        @bot.event
        async def on_message_edit( before, after):
              await before.channel.send(
                    f'Before: {before.content}\n' f'After: {after.content}'


                

bot.run('token')
```

I have to do this because I just put if message.author.id == id in the on_message_edit it would return as false. I also tried to also use variables like if message.author.id == id then something = True, but it just won't work. But this doesn't quite work either, any suggestions as to how I could fix this?

Comment: Why create a new message edit event *and register it* inside of `on_message`? That should go outside the `on_message` listener at the very least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, avoid naming strings like `id` since it's used by discord.py already and can be confusing for python. I've changed it for `banned_id` just for this example.

Secondly, `message.author.id` is an integer value, so make sure you compare it to another integer value. If you make something like:

`banned_id = 142345353455345`

python treats it just like a string of characters, not a number. You can make it a number using `int()`.

For me this code works just fine:

```
    @bot.event
    async def on_message_edit(before, after):
        banned_id = int(YOUR_ID_HERE)

        if before.author.id == banned_id:
            await before.channel.send("you wish")
        else:
            await before.channel.send(f'Before: {before.content}\n' f'After: {after.content}')
```

Comment: Well the problem here is I want it so any of the edits made by this id won't be reacted to by the bot. But I do appreciate the suggestion to avoid using var strings like id.

Comment: @NoobieAtCoding I edited my answer so the example includes editing the message. It really works fine. You can replace `await before.channel.send("you wish")` by simple `pass` and the bot won't react.

Comment: Yeah I mean it does work, but like I want it to make it so when the bot detects this user it won't react to messages this user has edited. I tried to put this in on_message_edit but it just says "unresolved reference "message"".

Comment: sorry I didn't saw the edit before, let me try.

Comment: @NoobieAtCoding check out my first answer. I just now edited the block of code so it does what you want, really. :)